# Change .css file from javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have this in a CSS file:

```
#tabs .bg {
    background: url("../images/bg-tabs-r.gif") no-repeat scroll 100% 0 transparent;
    height: 39px;
    line-height: 42px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Through JavaScript how do I change `background` to blank color and `line-height` to `28px`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it directly on your element:

```
mytab=document.getElementById("tabs");
mytab.style.background="white";
mytab.lineHeight="28px";
```

Comment: This will not remove the bg img.

Comment: Why white? Your assuming the element is on a white background?

Comment: That was just to put a color in it. Red orange or whatever [HTML valid colorname](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp) would stand as well.

Comment: Tanks for all your help, the two examples work just fine for me :) I cant put the check in the two?

Answer (score 4):

If you use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) (you should) it's very easy:

```
$('#tabs .bg').css({'background': 'none', 'line-height': '28px'});
```

Comment: jQuery isn't required for this. Just makes the page heavier.

Comment: can i call it inside `<script type="text/javascript"> </script>` ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to include the jQuery library first. If you don't want to install jQuery use caffein's answer.

Comment: @caffein - I think that depends on how much JS is actually involved and how complicated it's getting. jQuery doesn't actually add very much, especially if you load it from a CDN (increases the chance that the browser will just pick up a cached version), especially if you're using a lot of JS already. That said, if this is the only JS the OP is using, they probably don't *need* jQuery and it very well could be overkill if vanilla JS works cross browser.